# Complex PHP Object to JSon String

Tags: php, object, json

I have a complex object in `PHP` and need to parse it to build a Json String. I found many exmaples i've found here and other sites, but no one worked. The further problem is that my hosting works on PHP 5.2 and i cannot upgrade.

Here is an example of my `var_dump($myObj)`:

```
object(Park)[4]
private 'idObj' => string '60304' (length=5)
private 'name' => string 'AlphaSurf' (length=9)
private 'address' => 
object(Address)[6]
  private 'idObj' => string '40304' (length=5)
  private 'street' => string 'Champ de la Vigne' (length=17)
  private 'number' => string '7' (length=1)
  private 'zip' => string '1470' (length=4)
  private 'city' => string 'Estavayer-le-Lac' (length=16)
  private 'country' => 
    object(Country)[8]
      private 'idObj' => string '30039' (length=5)
      private 'name' => string 'Switzerland' (length=11)
      private 'flag' => string 'switzerland.gif' (length=15)
  private 'usState' => null
private 'contactInfo' => 
object(ContactInfo)[7]
  private 'idObj' => string '70304' (length=5)
  private 'phone' => string '' (length=0)
  private 'email' => string '' (length=0)
  private 'emailcode' => null
  private 'confirmed' => string '1' (length=1)
  private 'website' => string 'www.alphasurf.ch' (length=16)
  private 'mobile' => string '' (length=0)
  private 'fax' => string '' (length=0)
  private 'newsletter' => string '0' (length=1)
private 'owner' => 
object(User)[9]
  private 'idObj' => string '50001' (length=5)
  private 'username' => string 'emaborsa' (length=8)
  private 'password' => string '5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8' (length=40)
  private 'type' => string 'ADMIN' (length=5)
  private 'state' => string 'ACTIVE' (length=6)
  private 'ip' => string '' (length=0)
  private 'time' => string '0' (length=1)
  private 'address' => null
  private 'contactInfo' => 
    object(ContactInfo)[11]
      private 'idObj' => string '1' (length=1)
      private 'phone' => null
      private 'email' => string 'info@emaborsa.com' (length=17)
      private 'emailcode' => null
      private 'confirmed' => string '1' (length=1)
      private 'website' => null
      private 'mobile' => null
      private 'fax' => null
      private 'newsletter' => string '1' (length=1)
private 'logo' => string 'Champ de la Vigne 71470' (length=23)
private 'xcoord' => string '46856912' (length=8)
private 'ycoord' => string '6846918' (length=7)
private 'state' => string 'HIDDEN' (length=6)
private 'detail' => 
object(ParkDetail)[10]
  private 'idObj' => string '1' (length=1)
  private 'descriptionIT' => string '' (length=0)
  private 'descriptionEN' => string '' (length=0)
  private 'descriptionDE' => string 'xcxcx' (length=5)
  private 'type' => string '' (length=0)
  private 'kickers' => string '0' (length=1)
  private 'boxes' => string '0' (length=1)
  private 'rails' => string '0' (length=1)
  private 'specials' => string '0' (length=1)
  private 'specialsDescriptionIT' => null
  private 'specialsDescriptionEN' => null
  private 'specialsDescriptionDE' => null
  private 'dimension' => string '0' (length=1)
private 'lastPayment' => null
```

All properties are private but there are public getters and setters.

Comment: What's wrong with using `json_encode`?

Comment: All the properties are private? what are you going to do with the json?

Comment: You can try serialize / unserialize functions.

Comment: you could give your classes a toJson method where you create an array consisting of your private variables and the njson_encode and return it?.

Comment: `json_encode($myObj)` returns `{}`

Comment: `"what are you going to do with the json?"` is it important?

Comment: You should really find a way to upgrade. If necessary, change hosts. [PHP 5.2 came out more than 7 years ago, and even the most recent PHP 5.2.x release was over three years ago.](http://php.net/releases/).

Comment: The properties are private, dumping them to a json string would probably mean they shouldn't be private or you shouldn't need them in the json string

Comment: @YRM i think you should take a look to the OOP (Incapsulating and informationhidind)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
public function encodeJSON() 
{    
    foreach ($this as $key => $value) 
    { 
         if($value instanceOf(stdClass)){
             $json->$key = $value->encodeJSON();
         }else
             $json->$key = $value; 
    } 
    return json_encode($json);
}
```

i'm trying to move the private members to a new object that can be written by normal `json_encode()` and in line 6 i'm calling it recursively foreach parameter if it not a primative type

Comment: ...well, where do i have to put it?

Comment: into the class you want to echo json of it,  use `$this->encodeJSON()` and you have to write it into every object that have private members you want to JSON it

Comment: Does it work if i create an Json class with this method and i extend each class from this new Json class?

Comment: it worked by adding the below code into each class. Defining a single one inherited by all classes doesn't work.

Comment: And you are telling me to read about encapsulation? Your properties are private so if you put this method in a class and extend it won't be able to access the private properties.

Comment: @MajedDH would have been nice if you quoted the original answer you pasted yours from.

Answer (score 1):

I think you made a design mistake by needing to expose private property values.

But of course there are scenarios where this should be done.
As pointed out by [PHP Object To JSON format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796596/php-object-to-json-format/14796817#14796817) one way of doing this would be trough reflection.

Here is a simple example using php ReflectionClass to achieve what you want:

```
function getJson($object)
{
    $result = array();
    $refl = new ReflectionClass($object);
    foreach ($refl->getProperties() as $prop) {
        $prop->setAccessible(true);
        $result[$prop->name] = $prop->getValue($object);
    }
    return json_encode($result);
}
```

Comment: that work really well for my complexe object. This solution doesn't add crazy name in the json object!

Answer (score 0):

As you're running PHP < 5.4, I'd recommend creating a `toArray` method in your objects, returning an array containing all the properties (without bothering if they are public, private or protected).

For example :

```
public class Park {

    private $idObj;
    private $address;

    public function toArray() {

        $toArray = array(
            'idObj' => $this->idObj,
            'address' => $this->address->toArray() // Assuming address is an Address object
        );
    }
}
```

Do this in all your classes and sub-classes and then you can use :

```
$park = new Park(/* your values to initialize the object */);
echo json_encode($park->toArray());
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the best way? I have 25 classes, i would have to do it in each single class. I guess there must be a way to do it through reflection in one single class or something else.

Comment: Well, with PHP 5.4 came the `JsonSerializable` interface that might have helped but with an earlier version of PHP, it's way more 'complicated' to achieve this. I'd suggest you have a look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4697671/831669 and this one : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14796817/831669

Comment: I've already seen an example like this, it'd mean that i have to write a proper method for every class...

Comment: @Emaborsa or upgrade your outdated PHP version.